# How to get custom post type to display post meta on archive pages?

Tags: post-meta

I have a created a custom post type but on category archive pages the post meta information is not displayed.

This is the code used to display the post meta:

```
<?php if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ) codilight_meta_1();?>
```

And this is the above function's code:

```
function codilight_meta_1() {
$time_string = '<time class="entry-date published updated" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time>';
if ( get_the_time( 'U' ) !== get_the_modified_time( 'U' ) ) {
    $time_string = '<time class="entry-date published" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time>';
}

$time_string = sprintf( $time_string,
    esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
    esc_html( get_the_date() )
);

$posted_on = sprintf(
    esc_html_x( '%s', 'post date', 'codilight' ),
    '<span class="entry-date">' . $time_string . '</span>'
);
$byline = sprintf(
    esc_html_x( '%s', 'post author', 'codilight' ),
    '<span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="' . esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ) . '">' . esc_html( get_the_author() ) . '</a></span>'
);

echo '<div class="entry-meta entry-meta-1">';

    echo $byline.$posted_on;
    if ( ! post_password_required() && ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) ) {
        echo '<span class="comments-link">';
        echo '<i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i>';
        comments_popup_link( '0', '1', '%' );
        echo '</span>';
    }

echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: `'post'` is not a custom post type.

Comment: if you put the code of codilight_meta_1(), we'll able to tell you if you need to echo or not the result of your function. And as @birgire told you if you create a cpt, you code will not shown this condition (based on post).

Comment: Yes, I realize `'post'` is not a custom post type but i wasn't sure what changes needed to be made.

Comment: @Benoti I added the full code. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes "post" is the standard post-type, if you create a new one, you need to replace "post" with the post-type you need.

Comment: Ok, but I need to change it so it works for both standard posts and the custom post type.

Comment: This needs to work for both 'post' and the custom post type ('reviews').

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change,

```
<?php if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ) codilight_meta_1();?>
```

to

```
<?php if ( 'post' === get_post_type() || 'reviews' === get_post_type()) codilight_meta_1();?>
```

Comment: Or use `in_array` like this:

`if ( in_array( get_post_type(), array( 'post', 'reviews' ) ) ) codilight_meta_1();`

Comment: Thanks, the first answer you gave is working. I did try something like that before but I was getting an error. don't know what I was doing wrong but at least it's working now. Thanks for your help.